# XML schema declarations in XML file breaks XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xmlschema

I have an XSD, XML and XSLT file.

(simplified) XML:

```
<project
xmlns="SYSTEM"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="SYSTEM schema.xsd">

<property name="name1" value="value1">
<property name="name2" value="value2">
</project>
```

In my XSLT i need to perform a transformation for every element in `<project>` using `<xsl:for-each` tag.
But the transformation only works properly when i remove the `xmlns, xmlns:xsi` and `xsi:schemaLocation` attributes from `<project>`.
(I of course tested it without these attributes and it works fine.)

This is the faulty result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project/>
```

Here's my xslt file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
            <project>
            <xsl:for-each select="project/*">
                <property>
                    <xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></xsl:attribute>
                    <xsl:attribute name="value"><xsl:value-of select="@value"/></xsl:attribute>
                </property>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </project>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the top lines of my xsd file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <xs:schema
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="SYSTEM" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
    targetNamespace="SYSTEM"
    elementFormDefault="qualified"
    vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="project">
```

Comment: To find 727 other people who have fallen into the same trap, search on "XSLT default namespace".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML has a default namespace. So your XSLT needs to define it with some prefix. And you need to prepend that namespace prefix when you are referring to any element. I used `xmlns:a="SYSTEM"` for that.

Please see below.

> XSLT

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:a="SYSTEM">

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select="a:project/a:property"/>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: For the attributes in the sample you need to use the unprefixed name like `@name` or `@value`, they are not in any namespace.

Comment: @MartinHonnen, thanks for  the clarification. I adjusted the verbiage of the proposed solution.